# ASP MVC passing model data in view back as form data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I got the following Razor view that display a list of HDD so an user and add to a cart. When the user press the button next to each row of HDD, it will pass the quantity and HDD's identity to a controller. However, while each HDD's ID does display properly, "hddId" is always 1 and "quantity" is correctly 5 when I inspect the Controller's parameters.

```
@model IEnumerable<TestStore.Models.Hdd>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
@using(Html.BeginForm("AddToCart","Cart")){
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Ident
        </th>
        <th>
            Brand
        </th>
        <th>
            Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Model
        </th>
        <th>
            Speed
        </th>
        <th>
            Capacity
        </th>
        <th>
            Cache
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.hddId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.Hidden("hddId", item.hddId)
            @Html.Hidden("quantity", 5)
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.brand)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.model)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.speed)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.capacity)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.cache)
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Add to Cart" />
        </td>
    </tr>

}

</table>
}
```

Comment: Yes, I hard-coded 5 for "quantity" and the controller does see 5 for that parameter.

Comment: Your submit button does not reference a particular row and I think will submit the whole form instead of the row in which it was clicked. I think there should be a way to specify the Id and quantity for each row so the submit knows what value to submit

Answer (score 0):

Codingbiz is correct. The submit button wasn't referring to any particular row but the entire table. I suspect the reason why "hddId" was always "1" is because that's the first reference of "hddId" it see when the form is submitted. I changed it so @using(Html.BeginForm(...)) is inside the @foreach loop so each row has its own form and submit button:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {

    <tr>
        @using(Html.BeginForm("AddToCart","Cart")){
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.hddId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.Hidden("hddId", item.hddId)
            @Html.Hidden("quantity", 5)
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.brand)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.model)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.speed)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.capacity)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.cache)
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Add to Cart" />
        </td>
        }
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: While this might work, it's not legal html.  `<tr>` can only contain `<th>` and `<td>` elements.  There is no guarantee this will work in any browser, or continue to work in any browser in the future.

Comment: I moved the @using(...) block to just outside the <tr> block, would that still be considered illegal html format since it's still inside the <table> tag?

Comment: No.  The only valid elements inside a table tag are caption, col, colgroup, thead, tbody, or tr.  The @using does not appear in the rendered html, it is just a mechanism to render the form tag and all the content within it. form is not legal within the table tag, or within the tr tag, only within th and td tags.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, this doesn't work because when you submit, you're submitting every row in the table, not just the one clicked.

One option is to do what they suggest in this article:

http://federmanscripts.com/2010/01/12/form-and-table-row-nesting-workaround/

That is, using javascript, you copy the form values on button press to a hidden row and submit that.

Answer (score 0):

I got around the validation problem by using button type="submit" instead of input type="submit".  It still works correctly by passing the id number to the controller.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("AddToCart","Cart")){
<table>
    <tr>
    //header stuff here
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
    //row data goes here
    //remove hidden field reference to @item.hddId
    <tr>
    <td>
        <button type="submit" value="@item.hddId" name="hddId">Add to Cart</button>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
}
```